# JavaFX, TableView - Is HashMap<personName, List<Events>> or HashMap<day, List<Events>> the solution to my problem

Tags: java, javafx, hashmap, tableview, fxml

I'm at a crossroads right now. The problem I'm having is coloring in the cells of the `TableView<Person>.` I have 3 columns: `firstName, lastName, and the Days Column` (which is actually 60 columns representing the next 60 days from today). Each `Person` will have something to do on these days called "`events`" (1 event max per day, with a `startDate` and `endDate`). Each person can therefore have up to 60 events when I read them from an XML file. Here's a picture to illustrate what I am referring too.

[Scheduler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smJ0J.jpg)

This is the Person class

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import stack.Event;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Person{
private StringProperty name;
private StringProperty last;
private String group;
private ArrayList<Event> events;
static ArrayList<String> strDays = new ArrayList<String>();

public ArrayList<Event> getEvents() {
    return events;
}

public void setEvents(ArrayList<Event> events) {
    this.events = new ArrayList<>(events);
}

public String getName() {
return name.get();
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name.set(name);;
}

public StringProperty nameProperty(){
return name;
}

public String getLast() {
return last.get();
}

public void setLast(String last) {
this.last.set(last);
}

public StringProperty lastProperty(){
return last;
}

public String getGroups() {
return group;
}

public void setGroups(String group) {
this.group = group;
}
public Person(String name, String last, String group, ArrayList<Event> events){
    this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
    this.last = new SimpleStringProperty(last);
    this.group = group;
    this.events = new ArrayList<Event>(events);
}
public static void print(){
Date current = new Date(); //current first date 
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy\n MM/dd\n E"); //format wanted
ArrayList<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>(); 

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(current);
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 60); //setting the tableView end date

Date startDate = current;
Date endDate = cal.getTime();

Calendar c1 = DateToCalendar(startDate);
Calendar c2 = DateToCalendar(endDate);  

//this generates all the dates between the start date and end date
while (!areEqualDate(c1, c2)){
    ft.format(c1.getTime());
    dates.add(c1.getTime());
    c1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,1);
}

    //this formats the dates
    for (int i = 0; i < dates.size(); i++){
        strDays.add(i, ft.format(dates.get(i)));
        }

    }


private static boolean areEqualDate(Calendar c1, Calendar c2) {
if (c1.get(Calendar.YEAR) != c2.get(Calendar.YEAR)) 
    return false; 
if (c1.get(Calendar.MONTH) != c2.get(Calendar.MONTH)) 
    return false; 
if (c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) != c2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)) 
    return false; 

return true;
}

private static Calendar DateToCalendar(Date startDate) {
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(startDate);
return cal;
}
}
```

The Event class

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

public class Event {

    private String event;
    private String startDate;
    private String endDate;

public String getStartDate() {
    return startDate;
}

public void setStartDate(String startDate) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
}

public String getEndDate() {
    return endDate;
}

public void setEndDate(String endDate) {
    this.endDate = endDate;
}

public Event(){
    this.event= "";
    this.startDate = "";
    this.endDate = "";
}

public Event(String event, String startDate, String endDate){
    this.event = event;
    this.startDate = startDate;
    this.endDate = endDate;
}

public String getEvent() {
    return event;
}

public void setEvent(String event) {
    this.event = event;
}       

}
```

My sample.fxml class, package name of my project is **stack**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox?>
<?import java.lang.String?>
<?import javafx.collections.FXCollections?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.cell.*?> 
<?import javafx.collections.*?> 
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SeparatorMenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?> 

<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
  fx:controller="stack.Controller" fx:id="container">
   <center>
        <GridPane alignment="CENTER">
            <padding>
                <Insets top="40" left="20" bottom="20" right="20"></Insets>
            </padding>
            <?language javascript?>
            <Label fx:id="title" text="Scheduler" alignment="CENTER" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0"></Label>
            <TableView fx:id="table" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS" editable="true">
                <columnResizePolicy>
                    <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                </columnResizePolicy>
                <columns>
                        <TableColumn fx:id="firstColumn" text="First Name" minWidth="100" maxWidth="100">
                            <cellValueFactory>
                                <PropertyValueFactory property="name"/>
                            </cellValueFactory>
                        </TableColumn>
                        <TableColumn fx:id="secondColumn" text="Last Name" minWidth="100" maxWidth="120">
                            <cellValueFactory>
                                <PropertyValueFactory property="last" />
                            </cellValueFactory>
                        </TableColumn>
                                </columns>
            </TableView>
                <fx:script>          
                    table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
                    table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
                </fx:script>
        </GridPane>
    </center>
 </BorderPane>
```

Main class

```
import javax.print.DocFlavor.URL;

import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;

public class main extends Application {       
    public Scene theme;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));               
            primaryStage.setTitle("Stack");
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 650); 
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();    
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My code is wrong but I have an understanding why it's doing what it's doing. this is what I have currently in my
Controller class

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringWrapper;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TablePosition;
import javafx.scene.control.TableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

    public TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
    public TableColumn<Person, String> firstColumn, secondColumn, days;
    public TableColumn[] tablecols;
    //public TableColumn<Person, Event> days;
    int count = 0;
    //TempTestClass test = new TempTestClass();
    private  String current = "";
    ArrayList<String> dayArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        Person.print();

        dayArray = new ArrayList<String>(Person.strDays);

        tablecols = new TableColumn[dayArray.size()];
        System.out.println("tablecols size: " + tablecols.length);
        String start = "";
        //in each day for the next 60 days
        for (int i = 0; i < tablecols.length; i++){
            days = new TableColumn<>(dayArray.get(i));
            days.setText(dayArray.get(i));
            days.setMinWidth(55);

            table.getColumns().add(days);

            current = dayArray.get(i);
            //days.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(cellData.getValue().getEvents().toString()));
            //days.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(cellData.getValue().getEvents().get(0).getEvent()));
            for (Person p:getPerson()){           
                if (p.getEvents().size() != 0){ 
                    for (int j = 0; j < p.getEvents().size(); j++){
                        start = p.getEvents().get(j).getStartDate(); 
                        String sub = start.substring(0, 5);

                        // I think we're good here, it gets all the valid days that there's at least one event on
                        if (current.contains(sub)){
                            System.out.println(sub);
                            specific(); 
                        }
                    }
                } } }

        /*These two do not work here*/
        //specific();
        //days.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(cellData.getValue().getEvents().get(0).getEvent().toString()));                
        table.setItems(getPerson());
        table.setEditable(true);       
        table.setStyle("-fx-selection-bar: grey;"); //default cell color  
    }    
/*******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************/    
/*******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************/    


public void specific(){     //loops through each column?
    days.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Person, String>, 
        TableCell<Person, String>>(){
            @Override
            public TableCell<Person, String> call(
                    TableColumn<Person, String> param){
             return new TableCell<Person, String>(){
               @Override
               protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty){
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (empty){ //item is null, meaning there's nothing there?
                        setText(null);
                        setGraphic(null);
                    } else {
                        int currentIndex = indexProperty()
                            .getValue() < 0 ? 0
                            : indexProperty().getValue();               
                            ArrayList<Event> type = param //basically person.getEvents()
                            .getTableView().getItems()
                            .get(currentIndex).getEvents();
                            Person person = getTableView().getItems().get(currentIndex);

                        for (int i = 0; i < type.size(); i++){
                            String task = type.get(i).getEvent();
                            /*String day = type.get(i).getStartDate();
                            String sub = day.substring(0, 5);*/
                        if (type.get(1).getEvent().equals("International Travel")){
                            setStyle("-fx-background-color: orange"); 
                            setText(task);
                        }
                        if (type.get(i).getEvent().equals("PTO")){
                            setStyle("-fx-background-color: green"); 
                        setText(task);
                        }  
                        else{
                           setStyle(""); //invisible column but still "filled in"
                           setText(task);
                        }
                       }                    
                      }
                    };
                };
          }
    });
    }

public ObservableList<Person> getPerson(){
        ObservableList<Person> person = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

     ArrayList<Event> eventArray = new ArrayList<Event>();
     eventArray.add(new Event("International Travel", "09/22/2018", "09/22/2018"));
            eventArray.add(new Event("International Travel", "09/30/2018", "09/30/2018"));
            eventArray.add(new Event("PTO", "10/02/2018", "10/02/2018"));
     ArrayList<Event> diffArray = new ArrayList<Event>();
            diffArray.add(new Event("Personal", "09/22/2018", "09/22/2018"));
            diffArray.add(new Event("PTO", "09/30/2018", "09/30/2018"));
            diffArray.add(new Event("PTO", "10/02/2018", "10/02/2018"));
        person.add(new Person("John", "Smith", "GroupA", eventArray));
        person.add(new Person("Karen", "O", "GroupA", eventArray));
        person.add(new Person("Jane", "Doe", "GroupB", diffArray));
        person.add(new Person("Mike", "Johnson", "GroupA", eventArray));
        person.add(new Person("Dukes", "Clan", "GroupB", diffArray));

          return person;        
    }
}
```

So basically what's going on from the above complete **Compilable** code is if Dukes has events on 09/22, 09/30, and 10/02, which the `event` **Personal** is only on the 22nd, and **PTO** on the other days of the 30th and 2nd. The 09/22 `day column` will be blue because the cellFactory will look at the events that Dukes has (which is 3) in that cell, of every cell belonging to Dukes, and then will see that **"Oh, she does have a PTO event in her event array, so let's make the whole cell blue"**. The day columns are important to me and I've thought about putting something like `(If PTO && PTO.startDay.equals(dayColumn.getText))`, but it'll be ugly and still wouldn't work accurately. I don't know how to be flexible with it. I can only hardcode it to make it look like what I want but it's bad logic, my code is bad logic which is why I'm asking if Hashmap is the way to go before I go through that route, or is there a simple implementation or something I'm overlooking?

Would I need one HashMap or two? because my thinking is that there must be a way to map the person, and day through the event.

Something like this
[Mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hg97n.jpg)

I've searched other links and I think it can be done but I just wanted to get an opinion as to whether a hashmap is needed to accomplish what I want and also on what I've been doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem (not uncompileable snippets)

Comment: @Matt I just did it like that to shorten the length of the post but I'll make it complete and correct now

Comment: To whoever may look for something similar, this post helped me get what I wanted [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639108/javafx-tableview-objects-with-maps)